# sqlserver foreign key constraint on lookup table

Tags: sql-server, foreign-keys, constraints

Looking for the correct design to handle this situation (this example isn't real, just displaying the concept of my question):

Let's say you have tblStates that is used as a lookup table controlling what states can be selected in tblEmployees (tblEmployees.state). There is a foreign key constraint on tblEmployee so you can only select states existing in tblStates.

I want the end-user to be able to delete states from tblStates, but this is restricted if tblEmployees has a record with the same state targeted for deletion. I want to allow the end user to delete the state in tblStates and have it remain in existing rows of tblEmployees. It should only restrict the deleted state when users make updates going forward.

Comment: What you describe isn't a foreign key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way such a scenario is usually handled is by marking the row in tblStates as inactive, but not deleting it from the table.

To do this, you would add a boolean column (IsDeleted for example), and set it when you no longer want the state to be visible to the user for new rows in tblEmployees.

This preserves the integrity of your data, and enables you to still work with the tblEmployees table in a same way, regardless of whether the associated tblStates row was deleted or not (by Joining the tables for example)

Comment: Thanks, I believe this will work great for what I'm doing. I remember seeing this same concept in another db (they had an 'archived' column with a Y/N flag doing just that).

Answer (score 1):

Considering that you want to keep the `FOREIGN KEY` constraint in place. In that case, don't actually delete the record from `tblStates` table on end user deletion; rather have a separate column in `tblEmployees` saying `State_Status` and update that column with `DELETED` status probably (OR) a have a `BIT` column say `IsStateDeleted` and set it to `TRUE`.

Answer (score 0):

What you seem to be describing is the ability to use or not use a state, depending on if it is available and not 'deleted'; delete I think is not a physical operation in this instance.  For the tblStates table, why don't you create an instead of trigger and then if someone deletes a state, simply set a flag 'deleted' in the trigger, so someone else coming along can't use that state. Referential Integrity will still be valid since the state exists in tblStates.